# Integer solution if $b>2$ for $\frac{2^a +1}{2^b -1}$

Tags: number-theory

More specifically, prove that $\dfrac{2^a +1}{2^b -1}$ has no integer solutions for $b>2$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\ $ By division $\ a = qb + r,\,\ r<b,\,$ so $\ 2^a+1 = (\color{#c00}{2^{qb}\!-1})2^r + 2^r+1.\,$

By $\,2^b-1\mid \color{#c00}{2^{qb}-1}\,$ it follows that $\smash[t]{\,2^b-1\mid \overbrace{2^a+1}\iff 2^b-1\mid \overbrace{2^r+1}}.$

Show the latter divisibility can't hold because $\,\ b> r\,\Rightarrow\, 2^b- 1 > 2^r+1,\, $ using $\,b> 2.$

Answer (score 0):

In the *algebraic* way. Firstly $a>b$, otherwise $ b>2 \text{ and } a \leq b \Rightarrow 2^a+1<2^b-1 \Rightarrow 0< \dfrac{2^a +1}{2^b -1} < 1 \notin \Bbb{Z}$, so $a>b$, then you can write
$$\frac{2^a +1}{2^b -1} = \frac{2^{a-b}(2^b-1)+2^{a-b}+1}{2^b -1} = 2^{a-b}+\frac{2^{a-b}+1}{2^b-1}=2^{a-b}+\frac{2^c +1}{2^b -1}$$ then you go on rewriting the numerator of the function, until you get $$\frac{2^a +1}{2^b -1} =2^{a-b}+\frac{2^c +1}{2^b -1} = \ldots = 2^{a-b}+2^{c-b}+2^{d-b}+\ldots + \frac{2^x +1}{2^b -1}$$ where $x<b$. But $x<b \Rightarrow \frac{2^x +1}{2^b -1} \notin \Bbb{Z} \Rightarrow $
$$2^{a-b}+2^{c-b}+2^{d-b}+\ldots + \frac{2^x +1}{2^b -1} = \frac{2^a +1}{2^b -1} \notin \Bbb{Z}$$
*Q.E.D*